# SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<' caused by Heroku's Main.js after rollback

Tags: javascript, reactjs, heroku

I build a react app using the create-react-app which gets deployed on Heroku. Everything worked until I had to do a rollback using Heroku's rollback feature.

Now, whenever I try to access my website i get a `SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'` error.
When checking where the error comes from I can see in my network tab that the request for `main.28bbbf43.js` returns a `text/html` file instead of the expected `text/javascript`.
When pasting the request url in my browser I get a 404.
At this point I am lead to think that the `main.28bbbf43.js` has not been deployed correctly.

But then comes the tricky part:
If I try to access my site from a private browser of from an other pc it loads correctly and the `main.28bbbf43.js`gets returned as the expected `text/javascript`format.

I have only very little experience using Heroku.
Would anyone have an idea how this can be caused and how this should be fixed?

Comment: See if [clearing the cache](https://help.heroku.com/18PI5RSY/how-do-i-clear-the-build-cache) will help.

Comment: @Andy clearing the cache did the job but was kind of annoying I would have to contact all my clients to do this as well... Did an other deployment a bit later and the problem didn't return. Weird but oh well